# Python - Parse a string and convert it into list

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I've a string

```
a = "sequence=1,2,3,4&counter=3,4,5,6"
```

How do I convert it into a list,ie

```
sequence = [1,2,3,4]
counter = [3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) ([`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) in Python 3.x) to parse query string:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> a = "sequence=1,2,3,4&counter=3,4,5,6"
>>> {key: [int(x) for x in value[0].split(',')]
...  for key, value in urlparse.parse_qs(a).items()}
{'counter': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'sequence': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

items = "sequence=1,2,3,4&counter=3,4,5,6".split('&')

pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')

for i in items:
    print [int(i) for i in re.findall(pattern, i)]
```